# External clocking of MSP430 with variable duty cycle clock

Tags: clock, msp430

I'm going to clock an MSP430FR5969 using a PCF2127 RTC. The PCF2127 can output 32.768kHz at a duty cycle between 40%-60% and 16.384kHz, 8.192kHz, etc at exactly 50%. I will use the MSP's DCO system to generate an 8Mhz internal clock from this LF input.

Will the variable duty cycle @ 32.768kHz be a problem or should I change the RTC output to 16.384kHz to guarantee a 50% duty cycle?

Comment: Should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/msp430fr5969) says in section 5.2.13 (Clock Specifications):

> LFXT oscillator duty cycle: MIN: 30%, MAX: 70%